# Where did Xamarin deploy my application

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Total noob question. Xamarin studio is successfully deploying my application to my physical device, however I can't find "where" it is in the phone's file system. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I'm hoping to get access to the SQLLite3 database file being created. I assume that will be in a program folder somewhere with the application's assemblies.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Look in `/data/data/<your.package.name>`.

Comment: Thanks - but no luck. /data is empty.
If I go to /sdcard/Android there are a stack of directories in there for given applications. But nothing that seems to match mine. Also, they don't seem to have any files in there, except under a /cache folder
I'm wondering if there's some kind of permission thing going on. I don't have root access on the device. I'm using ES File Explorer, with "Show Hidden Files" set to true. 
Thanks again.

Comment: /data is empty because you do not have permissions to read it, I.e. you do not have root access.

Comment: Thanks. So, out of interest, is 'best practise' to develop on a rooted phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing your application is in debug mode, here be some terminal witchcraft that will do this:

1. Open a terminal window and connect to your device using adb: `adb shell`
2. Change the shell user to your package: `run-as your.package.name`
3. Get the full path to the current directory: `pwd`

From here you can explore your applications deployment directory using `ls` and `cd` to find whatever it is that you need.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I wouldn't have found that in a million years. I think that I'll need to root one of my devices....